# Mezzanine blog posts missing after database transfer?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, mezzanine

I'm working on a Django/Mezzanine site deployed on Heroku. After getting it running locally I deployed it, and synced the development database to the production one using [this method](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

When I visited the site it looked fine, but on the blog listing there were no posts listed, but there were pagination controls showing 2 pages, which is the right number.

[image]

In the admin interface no blog posts are listed or accessible at all, but the total number of blog posts is correctly listed as 6.

[image]

When I create a new blog post, it contains a link to the previous blog post, and correctly shows the title of the last post I made on the local test site.

[image]

But when I click the link, I get a 404.

When I use psql to inspect the heroku database, all the posts are there. So why aren't the posts showing up on the site? Have I misconfigured Mezzanine in some way, or is there a special step in migrating the data I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be a stupid mistake, as usual. I was testing locally with Postgresql 9.4, and the Heroku Postgres was on 9.3. Upgraded the Heroku addon and everything is peachy.